# Ionic 3 lazy loaded modal/page takes too much time to appear for the first time

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a Page that I use as a Modal in my Ionic 3 App. And I have the problem that the first time I call it I can see how the button animation ends and still the Modals has not appear.

The second time I call it, it comes really fast.

This is my html (i

```
<ion-navbar color="primary">
    <button ion-button
            menuToggle>
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title text-capitalize>{{ 'FEEDBACK' | translate }}</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
        <button class="config-button"
                ion-button
                tappable
                (touchend)="openConfig()">
            <ion-icon name="md-more"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </ion-buttons>

</ion-navbar>
```

and the function

```
openConfig() {
    let profileModal = this.modalCtrl.create('ConfigModalPage' , { userId: 8675309 });
    profileModal.present();
}
```

If I remove the lazy load behavior it loads faster but it stills feels laggy the first time.

How can I speed up this modal?

Answer (score -1):

In your function you are not using lazy loading approach as your modal controller takes Component instead of a string.

ConfigModalPage should be string - 'ConfigModalPage'.

For that your Component has to have proper module configuration. If you can share those files I can help with that.

Side note - why are you using touchend event for the button?

Comment: I changed it from string to component name because I was testing how slow it was without lazy load. And the touchend was also for test if that helps.

Comment: well then you should give full context of what you are asking about.

Comment: Well I wrote "If I remove the lazy load behavior it loads faster but it stills feels laggy the first time."